# Importing Angular 2 css from npm?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-build

Id like to:

```
npm install some-css-component
```

And then from the corresponding angular 2 component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'some-component',
    styleUrls: [ 'some-css-component, ...' ]
})
```

Is there a way to configure the angular build to resolve the npm `some-css-component`?

Comment: `styleUrls` has to point to the relative location of the `css`. you'll have to figure the relative path from your `ts` file to the `node_modules/some-css-component/path/to/file.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import) like in [global styles](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles#global-styles):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'some-component',
    styles: [
        '@import "/node_modules/some-css-component/dist/css/styles.css"'
    ],
})
```